# Automatically create an array of unique names and their number of wins

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a sheet that I can use to track which heroes I need to practice in a game...
Want to manually input the following things:

> Map name (A2:A), Hero name (B2:B), Result (C2:C)
>
> I use D2 To make a unique list of heroes I've played.
>   =UNIQUE(B2:B)

But then I want to add a corresponding collumn of wins. But I have to manually copy the function below to each row in the D2 and below... Anything to work around that?

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B;E2;C:C;"Victory")
```

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

To create an array report, AKA crosstab report, use a [Pivot Report](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272898?hl=en&ref_topic=1258755&rd=1).

## Instructions

1. Prepare the data as a simple table.
2. Select the data
3. Click Data > Pivot Table...
4. Add the Name field to the Row section
5. Add the Result field to the Column section
6. Add the Name field to the values section. In Summarize by select COUNTA

### Example

Assume the following as the data.

```
+----+--------------+---------+
|    |      A       |    B    |
+----+--------------+---------+
|  1 | Name         | Result  |
|  2 | Batman       | Victory |
|  3 | Superman     | Victory |
|  4 | Batman       | Loss    |
|  5 | Lex Luthor   | Victory |
|  6 | Superman     | Victory |
|  7 | Batman       | Loss    |
|  8 | Lex Luthor   | Victory |
|  9 | Superman     | Victory |
| 10 | Batman       | Loss    |
| 11 | Wonder Woman | Loss    |
+----+--------------+---------+
```

### Result

```
+---+--------------+------+---------+-------------+
|   |      A       |  B   |    C    |      D      |
+---+--------------+------+---------+-------------+
| 1 |              | Loss | Victory | Grand Total |
| 2 | Batman       | 3    | 1       | 4           |
| 3 | Lex Luthor   |      | 2       | 2           |
| 4 | Superman     |      | 3       | 3           |
| 5 | Wonder Woman | 1    |         | 1           |
| 6 | Grand Total  | 4    | 6       | 10          |
+---+--------------+------+---------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more efficiently done with a single [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function, which can  identify unique entries and count the number of their qualifying appearances at once. For example, the following function returns two columns: one with unique names, another with the corresponding win counts (zero is none):

```
=query({B:B, arrayformula(n(C:C="Victory"))}, "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label sum(Col2) 'Victories'", 1)
```

Explanation:

- `arrayformula(n(C:C="Victory"))` is a column of 0s and 1s, where 1s are "Victory" rows. The query aggregates the data by taking the sum of the second column.
- `group by Col1` means aggregating the data for the same name
- `label sum(Col2) 'Victories'` is just for decoration

Note that the above query uses an array created on-the-fly with `{}` notation. This is why its columns are referred to as Col1 and Col2: they are not in the sheet, so do not have column letters like A,B,C.

#### Dropping zero-win names

If the names that don't have any wins are to be omitted, there is a simpler query:

```
=query(B:C, "select B, count(C) where C = 'Victory' group by B label count(C) 'Victories'", 1)
```

Explanation:

- `where C = 'Victory'` filters the rows
- `group by B` means aggregating the data for the same name
- `label count(C) 'Victories'`   is just for decoration

#### Example of usage

When applied to the data

```
+----+------+---------+
|    |  B   |    C    |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | Name | Result  |
|  2 | qq   | Victory |
|  3 | ww   | Victory |
|  4 | qq   | Loss    |
|  5 | ee   | Victory |
|  6 | ww   | Victory |
|  7 | qq   | Loss    |
|  8 | ee   | Victory |
|  9 | ww   | Victory |
| 10 | qq   | Loss    |
+----+------+---------+
```

the above formulas return

```
+---+------+-----------+
|   |  D   |     E     |
+---+------+-----------+
| 1 | Name | Victories |
| 2 | ee   |    2      |
| 3 | qq   |    1      |
| 4 | ww   |    3      |
+---+------+-----------+
```

Comment: Getting an error, can't seem to make any query string work what so ever. Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: ADD_COL_TO_GROUP_BY_OR_AGGB. Tried replacing the comma with semicolon as well. As that seems to be a difference to the documentation

Comment: Right, in your local setting you use semicolon after `B:C` But the rest should work as stated (I tested). Can you share a sheet where it fails to work.

Comment: Got it working, finaly. But I have another problem with that query though...
If I have only 1 loss and no wins, 'that collumn will show less results.
Thus making it out of sync with the names

Comment: Okay, I added a second query which will keep all the names, even those with 0 wins.